# Does orgmode have the option to restrict the task states or categories in the editing page?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to restrict the TODO types or categories in the editing page?

I know about filtering the agenda view, but I need the option to see only some tasks states in the editing page, such as PENDING, CANCELLED etc, or categories such as `:computing:emacs:vim:node:` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify todo states in a buffer with a line like this:

```
#+TODO: state1 state2 | state3
```

Then, when you cycle states on headlines in that buffer they will go through those. See https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html

Note the first time you add that line, you have to type C-c C-c on that line to refresh the local setup, but after that it should just work when you open the file.

You can specify file tags like

```
#+TAGS: computing emacs vim node
```

See https://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-tags.html